# jQuery Input Masks for datetime input using sql timestamp yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, jquery-plugins, timestamp

I'm using Robin Herbot's jQuery Input Masks plugin on my project.

It's very good but I need sql timestamp mask: yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss I don't konw if i'm doing something wrong but it seems datetime alias shows only hours and minutes.

I've tried some changes on mask but not successful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see the question is from long ago, I also came here while trying to learn **jquery.inputmask**.

Remember to always include what you have done (code sample) when asking a question. Even if it is wrong/not working, it will help the one providing an answer, and others looking for answers.

In general terms, I found it *somewhat* helpful to read through the **jquery.inputmask.*xxx*.extensions.js** files, where ***xxx*** = **date** in this instance. In there you can see how more complex aliases are constructed from more basic ones (by overriding the basic ones), and you can apply the same ideas in constructing a new alias if you don't find a useful one.

Code that should work for your case:

```
 $("#tsfield").inputmask("timestamp", { 
            mask:        "y/1/2 h:s:s",
            placeholder: "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss",
            separator:   "/",
            alias:       "datetime",
            hourFormat:  "24"
        });
```

... which creates a new alias named `timestamp`, overriding `datetime`, and applies it to the input with `id="tsfield"`.

If you have more than one input field with the same input mask on your page, I find it is better to create the new alias just once in your `$(document).ready()`, and then apply it by name to each field (refer to **jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js** and documentation for instructions).